# android itemView click listener weird behavior

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have this code in may recycler adapter which is created from a fragment passing getActivity() as an argument to the adapters constructor.

```
mAdapter = new OffersAdapter(getActivity());
```

it was working fine. that is starts the target activity.

however, suddenly when i click certain items in the list the target activity does not start but a new instance of the application is lunched ??? and it appears in Android Studio Monitor with a different id??

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(context, OfferDetails.class);
            final Offer offer = list.get(position);
            intent.putExtra("offer",offer);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: what is launch mode of `OfferDetails` activity ?

Comment: I never set a launch mode ..  and it was working as desired but suddenly the problem appeared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't related to click listener.
Actually, it's due to misuse of parcable object. The size of  extra object  is very large which causes stack overflow. So the app starts again causing described behaviour. 
I'd love to report this as an issue : the size of extra data is never checked. Isn't it better to chck against the size of  extra data and throw an exception if limits were exceded.